# React.js and adding css modules in React files

Tags: css, reactjs, module

I am following a React.js Tutorials..After ejecting there ae two files....webpack.config.dev.js and webpack.config.prod.js in the videos but in mine,there are only two webpack.config.js and webpackDevServer.js.In the video tutorials for css modules he adds in both config.prod.js and config.dev.js.I am confused why there is no config.prod.js in mine and will adding css modules only in webpack.config.js will work?

Comment: which version of Create-react-app and React did you use?